# Error including files after editing httpd-vhosts.conf

Tags: php, apache

I have edited my Apache httpd-vhosts.conf on windows to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/"
    ServerName mysite.local
</VirtualHost>
```

and /etc/hosts on windows to

```
##
# Host Database
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
##
#...
127.0.0.1           mysite.local
```

so as to access xampp from another PC. Before editing the above files, everything was working fine but after editing, Im getting an error that there is error accessing a file I have included. I am using the following code to include the file:

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
require_once($root."/mysite/models/login.php");
```

I also noticed using just require_once("../mysite/models/login.php") sometimes works and some other times I have to use require_once("../../mysite/models/login.php") for it work yet I am requiring them on the same code. What could be the problem? Can any one help me on how I should include the files after editing the apache file and windows etc/hosts file?

Comment: remove `/mysite/` from all of your require statements- since you are prefixing with the document root the path is resolving to `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite//mysite/models/login.php` you probably mean `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/models/login.php`

Comment: Thanks so much Orangepill. That worked perfectly